# Choosing from a List of methods in a tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

Good Day,

I'm new to this forum (and quite new to programming), so I hope my question is properly formulated.
I've been trying to create a GUI in python using tkinter, and I want to have two buttons calling methods of two different classes. One method is defining an integer, the second one is reporting content. I'd have a list of objects of the latter class, and I want to choose the right instance by the integer. Here's a MWE:

```
import tkinter as tk

class data:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

    def report(self):
        print("This is reported as self.content:" + str(self.content)) #This doesnt report the correct value for some reason?
        print("The Class does register the correct idx:" + str(Selector.idx))
        print("Using the Dict the correct value can be returned:" + str(vocables[Selector.idx].content))

class increment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = 0

    def increase(self):
        self.idx += 1
        print(self.idx)
        vocables[self.idx].report()

root = tk.Tk()
Selector = increment()
vocables = []
for id in range(10):
    vocables.append(data(id))
    # print(vocables[id].content)
CheckVocable = tk.Button(root, text="Report", command=vocables[Selector.idx].report)
CheckVocable.pack()
NextVocable = tk.Button(root, text="Increase Index", command=Selector.increase)
NextVocable.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I do not understand why the print of line 8 always reports the value of the first item in the list (vocabules[0] in this instance) instead of my desired value, which is returned in all other print cases. Am I messing up the work with classes or is the button behavior confusing me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***"why ... always ... first item in the list "***: `[Selector.idx]` is allways `0`. Doing `command=Selector.increase` does not change any in list `vocables`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in all other references the Selector.idx is set as intended (all other prints show values >0), so why is it always zero _only in the command line_?

Comment: I have to rephrase: Assingment to `command=...` are **static**. At the time you do the assignment, `Selector.idx` is `0`, therefore the assigned `class data` object is the first == 0 and get allways called on click.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you very much :)